# How to fetch only IDs from nested array in Hibernate?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have problem getting only ID from objects that are in nested collection in Hibernate.

Here is my code:

```
public class Company {

    private int id;
    private Set<Account> owners = new HashSet<Account>();

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Account.class)
    @Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "company_accountOwners",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    public Set<Account> getOwners() {
        return owners;
    }

    public void setOwners(Set<Account> owners) {
        this.owners = owners;
    }
```

Account.class

```
public class Account {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

How only get JSON with all Company.class data and array of owners (Account.class) that has only ID, not all other attributes (name, age)?
I'm in complete dark.

Json i get now:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "owners": [
    {
        "id": "testID",
        "name": "name",
        "age": 45
    }, 
    {
        "id": "testID2",
        "name": "name2",
        "age": 90
    }]
}
```

I want json like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "owners": [
    {
        "id": "testID"
    },
    {
        "id": "testID2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I have managed to get only array of owner ids, but i can not get whole parent class with it. `companyList = (ArrayList<Company>) session.createCriteria(Company.class)
                    .createAlias("owners", "ownersAlias")
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList() 
                            .add(Projections.property("ownersAlias.id").as("id")))
                    .list();`